# Javascript error in toPrecision() function

Tags: javascript

I want to use `toPrecision()` to reduce the size of a number before I display it.  However, I sometimes cannot multiply output of the function by another number without gaining a small rounding error.  See the code sample below:

```
var x = 0.0197992182093305
alert (x.toPrecision(4)) //Correct: 0.01980
alert (Number(x.toPrecision(4))) //Correct: 0.0198
alert( Number(x.toPrecision(4)) * 100) //Incorrect: 1.9800000000000002
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ueLsL460/4/ What's going on here?

Comment: It's not that function causing the problem. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/615754)  (amongst others).

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) None of the above numbers are exactly representable in binary floating-point, so don't expect it to be printed correctly without correct formatting

Comment: @EricBaldwin - I just made a slight modification to my answer to clarify that * 10 * 10 causes no problem - but only for this specific case. You could have a number where the loss of precision build up even with a * 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have a decimal equivalent - so in your case floating points are used. What this means is that Number(x.toPrecision(4)) doesn't give you exactly 0.0198, but something the FP binary number closest to 0.0198. So any arithmetic you do will be subject to the loss of precision introduced in floating point arithmetic. You can see the same effect if you do

```
 alert(0.0198 * 100);
```

By the way

```
  alert(0.0198 * 10 * 10);
```

gives you no problem (the loss of precision does not build up enough to make it into the digits Javascript deems to display) - but that's for this particular number alone.

Answer (score 4):

Based on what I understand, `Number(x.toPrecision(4)) * 100` creates a new Number object which will not inherit the precision of the parent.

If you still want it to be precise after Math, you need to put it in precision again.

```
alert((x * 100).toPrecision(4));
```

Technically, it's not an error. It's just the way javascript is supposed to work.

Comment: You don't need the `Number()` function here. `(x * 100).toPrecision(4)` will work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The use of primitive constructors is not that ideal, unless you are trying to do something trivial. Can you please try to do the code on the following fiddle and see if this will do for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/ueLsL460/5/

```
 var x = 0.0197992182093305;
 alert((x * 100).toPrecision(4));
```